# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3n+1}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3n+1}$

I've tried the ratio test but it was inconclusive... I tried to compare it to the divergent harmonic series then realized that's not how comparison works.. Help appreciated!

Comment: It diverges and *you can* compare it to $\sum\frac1n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong: that's *how* comparison works. The series diverges and this follows from$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\dfrac1{3n+1}}{\dfrac1n}=\frac13\in(0,\infty),$$together with the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: In my course we call this the limit comparison test. The comparison test would be $\sum \frac{1}{3n+1} < \sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ but the aligator is eating the wrong number for this comparison test to help us conclude about our series

Comment: Then use the fact that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{3n+1}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

The question is how to compare.  $\frac 1{3n+1} < \frac 1n$ will be the wrong way to compare as that gives us  $\sum \frac 1{3n+1} \le \sum \frac 1n = \infty$ and no coonclusion can be reached from there.

But notice $\frac 1{3n+1} < \frac 1{3n} < \frac 1{3(n-1)+1}=\frac 1{3n-2}$

Now 1:  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{3n+1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{3n-2}>\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{3n}$.

And 2: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{3n} = \lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac 1{3n}=$

$\frac 13 \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac 1n=$

$\frac 13 ([\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1n]-1)=$

$\frac 13(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1n) -\frac 13$

But $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1n$ diverges, so $\frac 13(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1n) -\frac 13$ and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{3n}$ does to.  So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{3n+1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{3n-2}>\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1{3n}$ does as well.